# Responsive layout in gmail app after adding <br /> tag breaks

Tags: css, email, gmail

I am using [Modular Template Patterns](https://github.com/mailchimp/email-blueprints) of MailChimp to create responsive email & it works like a charm.

**Main Issue:** I have created 3 col layout, each having some text and a button but since font renders a little different in different browsers and OS the text sometimes ends up having 2 lines in one col and 3 in other which creates horizontal dis-alignment of "buy now" buttons.

**It's solution creating new issue in Gmail App:** I added  `<br />` tag to break line so text is always distributed to 3 lines keeping button aligned but this broken layout in gmail app.

Here are screenshot with br tag on left and without br tag on right:

[image: Width <br>] .. [image: without <br>]

**Things I have tried:** I tried to set `<br />` tag to `display: none;` on mobile but it turns out gmail app doesn't respond to media query.

Instead of using `<br />` I used `div` tags to break lines but result was the same.

I tried setting `min-width` on col's table to 300, It fixed the problem but destroyed the layout on desktop email clients.

I believe when text doesn't push the layout to take the max width the layout doesn't expands to cover the entire width in gmail app and hence the 3 cols starts overlapping each other rather than taking full width, after text have been set to small chunks of 3 words rather than a full sentence.

I am running out of ideas, anything you guys believe can fix this issue I would love to try.

**Code Minified Version for un-minified [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/z5r2tk8b/):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><title>Test</title><!--
        This email is an experimental proof-of-concept based on the
        idea that the most common design patterns seen in email can
        be placed in modular blocks and moved around to create
        different designs.

        The same principle is used to build the email templates in
        MailChimp's Drag-and-Drop email editor.

        This email is optimized for mobile email clients, and even
        works relatively well in the Android Gmail App, which does
        not support Media Queries, but does have limited mobile-
        friendly functionality.

        While this coding method is very flexible, it can be more
        brittle than traditionally-coded emails, particularly in
        Microsoft Outlook 2007-2010. Outlook-specific conditional
        CSS is included to counteract the inconsistencies that
        crop up.

        For more information on HTML email design and development,
        visit http://templates.mailchimp.com
    --><style type="text/css">/*////// RESET STYLES //////*/
        body, #bodyTable, #bodyCell{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}
        table{border-collapse:collapse;}
        img, a img{border:0; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{margin:0; padding:0;}
        p{margin: 1em 0; background-color: #000; color: #fff;}

        .divider p     {background: #000 !important; color: #000 !important;}
        .divider p span{background: #000 !important; color: #000 !important;}

        /*////// CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES //////*/
        .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display emails at full width. */
        .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div{line-height:100%;} /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display line heights normally. */
        table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up. */
        #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook 2007 and up to provide a "view in browser" message. */
        img{-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;} /* Force IE to smoothly render resized images. */
        body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;} /* Prevent Windows- and Webkit-based mobile platforms from changing declared text sizes. */

        /*////// FRAMEWORK STYLES //////*/
        .flexibleContainerCell, .footer{padding-top:20px; padding-Right:20px; padding-Left:20px;}
        .flexibleImage{height:auto;}
        .bottomShim{padding-bottom:20px;}
        .imageContent, .imageContentLast{padding-bottom:20px;}
        .nestedContainerCell{padding-top:20px; padding-Right:20px; padding-Left:20px;}

        /*////// GENERAL STYLES //////*/
        body, #bodyTable{background-color:#232323;}
        #bodyCell{padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;}
        #emailBody{background-color:#000;}
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{color:#202020; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:20px; line-height:125%; text-align:Left;}
        .textContent, .textContentLast, .product-sec{color:#404040; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:16px; line-height:125%; text-align:Left;}
        .textContent a, .textContentLast a, .product-sec a{color:#2C9AB7; text-decoration:underline;}
        .nestedContainer{background-color:#E5E5E5; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;}
        .emailButton{background-color:#2C9AB7; border-collapse:separate; border-radius:4px;}
        .buttonContent{color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding:15px; text-align:center;}
        .buttonContent a{color:#FFFFFF; display:block; text-decoration:none;}
        .emailCalendar{background-color:#FFFFFF; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;}
        .emailCalendarMonth{background-color:#2C9AB7; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; text-align:center;}
        .emailCalendarDay{color:#2C9AB7; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:60px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; text-align:center;}@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){.product-sec{ padding-bottom: 30px !important; border-bottom: 1px solid #888 !important; padding-top: 16px !important;}.product-1-sec > table:first-child .textContent{ border-bottom: 1px solid #888 !important; padding-bottom: 30px !important; }.product-1-sec > table:first-child .textContent .textContent{ border-bottom: 15px solid #000 !important; padding-top: 0px !important; border-top: 1px solid #888 !important; padding-top: 31px !important;} .product-1-sec .logo-wrap tr:first-child .textContent{padding-top: 40px !important;}.mobile-item-top-space{ padding-top: 16px !important; }.footer{ padding-bottom: 10px !important; padding-top: 25px !important; } .inline-br{ content: ''; display: none !important;} .inline-br:after{content: '';} .mobile-has-top-border{border-top: 1px solid #888 !important; padding-top: 31px !important;}.mobile-has-bottom-border{ padding-bottom: 30px !important; border-bottom: 1px solid #888 !important; }/*////// CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES //////*/ body{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;}/* Force iOS Mail to render the email at full width. */ /*////// FRAMEWORK STYLES //////*/ /* CSS selectors are written in attribute selector format to prevent Yahoo Mail from rendering media query styles on desktop. */ table[id="emailBody"], table[class="flexibleContainer"]{width:100% !important;}/* The following style rule makes any image classed with 'flexibleImage' fluid when the query activates. Make sure you add an inline max-width to those images to prevent them from blowing out. */ img[class="flexibleImage"]{height:auto !important; width:100% !important;}/* Make buttons in the email span the full width of their container, allowing for left- or right-handed ease of use. */ table[class="emailButton"]{width:100% !important;}td[class="buttonContent"]{padding:0 !important;}td[class="buttonContent"] a{padding:15px !important;}td[class="textContentLast"],td[class="product-sec"] td[class="imageContentLast"]{padding-top:20px !important;}/*////// GENERAL STYLES //////*/ td[id="bodyCell"]{padding-top:10px !important; padding-Right:10px !important; padding-Left:10px !important;}.hide-in-mobile{display: none !important;}.show-in-mobile{display: inline-block !important; margin: 0 auto !important;}*[class="show"] {overflow: visible !important;float: none !important;display: block !important;line-height:100% !important;}</style><!--
        Outlook Conditional CSS

        These two style blocks target Outlook 2007 & 2010 specifically, forcing
        columns into a single vertical stack as on mobile clients. This is
        primarily done to avoid the 'page break bug' and is optional.

        More information here:
        http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css
    --><!--[if mso 12]>
        <style type="text/css">
            .flexibleContainer{display:block !important; width:100% !important;}
        </style>
    <![endif]--><!--[if mso 14]>
        <style type="text/css">
            .flexibleContainer{display:block !important; width:100% !important;}
        </style>
    <![endif]--></head><body style="margin: 0;padding: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #232323;height: 100% !important;width: 100% !important"><center><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #232323;height: 100% !important;width: 100% !important"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;height: 100% !important;width: 100% !important"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="emailBody" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #000"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="flexibleContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><tr><td class="product-1-sec" valign="top" width="600" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><table align="Left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="196" class="flexibleContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><tr><td valign="top" class="textContent" style="border: 15px solid #000;text-align: center;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #404040;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;line-height: 125%;padding-bottom: 20px"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="flexibleContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><tr><td valign="top" class="textContent" style="text-align: center;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #404040;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;line-height: 125%"><div style="color: #fff; text-align: center"><div style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1em; border-bottom: 5px solid #000; border-top: 15px solid #000">Receive</div><div style="font-size: 26px; line-height: 1em; color: #f5d18d; border-bottom: 17px solid #000">500</div><div style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.2em; color: #fff; border-bottom: 18px solid #000">Lorem ipsum dolor<br class="inline-br">sit amet, consectetur<br class="inline-br">adipisicing elit. In</div><div style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.2em; color: #fff">veniam id totam, esse<br class="inline-br">laboriosam dolores<br class="inline-br">fugiat, ducimus enim<br><br></div></div></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" style="text-align: center;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><a href="http://www.google.com/" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #2C9AB7;text-decoration: underline"><img style="max-width: 100%;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic" src="http://theprojectstagingserver.com/shazam/img/email/btn-buy-now-small_2x.jpg" width="115" alt="Buy Now"></a></td></tr></table></td><td valign="top" width="2px" class="hide-in-mobile divider" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #000"><img style="max-width: 100%;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;display: block" src="http://theprojectstagingserver.com/shazam/img/email/h-divider.png" width="2px"></td></tr></table><table align="Right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="394" class="flexibleContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><tr><td valign="top" class="textContent" style="text-align: center;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #404040;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;line-height: 125%"><table align="Left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="189" class="flexibleContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><tr><td valign="top" class="product-sec" style="border: 15px solid #000;text-align: center;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #404040;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;line-height: 125%;padding-bottom: 20px"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="flexibleContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><tr><td valign="top" class="textContent" style="text-align: center;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #404040;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;line-height: 125%"><div style="color: #fff; text-align: center"><div style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1em; border-bottom: 5px solid #000; border-top: 15px solid #000">Receive</div><div style="font-size: 26px; line-height: 1em; color: #f5d18d; border-bottom: 17px solid #000">500</div><div style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.2em; color: #fff; border-bottom: 18px solid #000">Lorem ipsum dolor<br class="inline-br">sit amet, consectetur<br class="inline-br">adipisicing elit. In</div><div style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.2em; color: #fff">veniam id totam, esse<br class="inline-br">laboriosam dolores<br class="inline-br">fugiat, ducimus enim<br><br></div></div></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" style="text-align: center;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><a href="http://www.google.com/" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #2C9AB7;text-decoration: underline"><img style="max-width: 100%;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic" src="http://theprojectstagingserver.com/shazam/img/email/btn-buy-now-small_2x.jpg" width="115" alt="Buy Now"></a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><table align="Right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="190" class="flexibleContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><tr><td valign="top" width="2px" class="hide-in-mobile" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #000"><img style="max-width: 100%;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic" src="http://theprojectstagingserver.com/shazam/img/email/h-divider.png" width="2px"></td><td valign="top" class="product-sec" style="border: 15px solid #000; text-align: center;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #404040;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;line-height: 125%;padding-bottom: 20px"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="flexibleContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><tr><td valign="top" class="textContent" style="text-align: center;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #404040;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;line-height: 125%"><div style="color: #fff; text-align: center"><div style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1em; border-bottom: 5px solid #000; border-top: 15px solid #000">Receive</div><div style="font-size: 26px; line-height: 1em; color: #f5d18d; border-bottom: 17px solid #000">500</div><div style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.2em; color: #fff; border-bottom: 18px solid #000">Lorem ipsum dolor<br class="inline-br">sit amet, consectetur<br class="inline-br">adipisicing elit. In</div><div style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.2em; color: #fff">veniam id totam, esse<br class="inline-br">laboriosam dolores<br class="inline-br">fugiat, ducimus enim<br><br></div></div></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" style="text-align: center;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><a href="http://www.google.com/" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #2C9AB7;text-decoration: underline"><img style="max-width: 100%;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic" src="http://theprojectstagingserver.com/shazam/img/email/btn-buy-now-small_2x.jpg" width="115" alt="Buy Now"></a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="flexibleContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" width="600" class="footer" style="padding-top: 20px;text-align: right;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;padding-right: 20px;padding-left: 20px"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%"><tr><td valign="top" class="textContent" style="text-align: right;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #404040;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;line-height: 125%;padding-bottom: 20px"><a href="http://www.google.com/" style="text-decoration: none;color: #fff;text-align: right;font-size: 9px;line-height: 1em;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%">Terms & Conditions apply*</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></center></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<br />` tag to force lines to be at-least 3. I have used multiple blank spaces `&nbsp;` at the end of sentence in a fashion that it keeps 3 line across browsers and devices.

As a result it fixed the issue on Gmail App and worked fine at other places as well.

**Edit:** It turns out that fix only worked for a specific width and on a slightly larger devices things started getting messy specially landscape which was slightly less than 600 width broke layout completely. I ended up not using responsive layout entirely.